# tensorflow - cannot restore model - "Couldn't match files for checkpoint"

Tags: tensorflow, save, restore

Here is my model saved to disk:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


BATCH_SIZE = 3
VECTOR_SIZE = 1
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE],
                   name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE],
                   name='labels_placeholder')

W = tf.get_variable('W', [VECTOR_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE])
b = tf.get_variable('b', [VECTOR_SIZE], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

y_hat = tf.matmul(W, x) + b
predict = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, x), b, name='predict')
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(y-y_hat)
train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(total_loss)
X = np.ones([BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE])
Y = np.ones([BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE])
all_saver = tf.train.Saver() 

sess= tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run([train_step], feed_dict = {x: X, y:Y})
save_path = r'C:\tmp\tmp\\'
all_saver.save(sess,save_path)
```

While trying to restore

```py
checkpoint_path = r'C:\tmp\tmp\\'
tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```py
ERROR:tensorflow:Couldn't match files for checkpoint C:\tmp\tmp\\
```

In `C:\tmp\tmp\` I have the following files:

```py
.data-00000-of-00001
.index
.meta
checkpoint
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the files just named line that? starting with dot?

If that is the case you should consider to save them differently because this could be the problem.

Try with:

`NUMBER_OF_CKPT = 60
 saver.save(sess,save_path,global_step=NUMBER_OF_CKPT)`

What is usually done is to save also the global_step as the number of the ckpt.

Hope to have solved it!

Comment: Your solution probably works. What I did, I simply wrote r'C:\tmp\tmp\prefix_name'. `prefix_name` is treated as prefix name and not as part of path in tensorflow.

Answer (score 3):

From saver.save tensorflow api:

> save_path: String. Path to the checkpoint filename. If the saver is sharded, this is the prefix of the sharded checkpoint filename.

In `save_path` you didn't specify checkpoint filename.

For future use, try setting:
`checkpoint_path = r'C:\tmp\tmp\my-model'`.

If you want to load your previously saved model, do the following:

1. prepend the string `my-model` for these files:

> ```
> .data-00000-of-00001
> .index
> .meta
> ```

2. modify `checkpoint` file such that it will point to your checkpoint:

> ```
> model_checkpoint_path: "C:\tmp\tmp\my-model"
> all_model_checkpoint_paths: "C:\tmp\tmp\my-model"
> ```

Loading the checkpoint should be now possible.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I saw this error while training a custom estimator on AI Platform (Cloud ML Engine). The issue for me was caused by the `region` of the GCS bucket where I was saving the checkpoints/model metadata.

When the `region` of this bucket was set to `us (multiple regions in United States)` I saw this error during evaluation. Setting the `region` of the GCS bucket to the same `region` where the AI Platform job was running (`us-central1 (Iowa)` in my case) resolved the issue.